# Laravel сортировка атрибутов модели

Tags: php, laravel, order

Есть модель

```
class Fine extends Model
{
   ...
   public function getStatusAttribute()
   {
      return ...
   }

}
```

Если мне нужно отсортировать по id например, то я пишу так

```
class FineController extends Controller
{
    ...
$this->model = $this->model->orderBy('id', $order);
```

Как близким способом отсортировать по статусу? (Атрибут читатель)

Comment: ->orderBy('status', $order) нет?

Comment: нет, если бы(..

Comment: getStatusAttribute это связь с другой таблицей откуда тянется статус?

Comment: @Sergey Она берет **поле1** из таблицы **Fine**, и **поле2** из **таблицы2**. `if(поле1==0 and поле2==0) status = 0; if(поле1==0 and поле2==1) status = 1;if(поле1==1 and поле2==1) status = 2;` ... и так далее

Comment: Я короче сделал тем вариантом , который я уже знал, через `public function scopeOrderByStatus($query, $order = 'asc')
    {

        $query->leftJoin(....` и далее сложный запрос. Если кто знает решение проще - пишите